# Build multiple "or" in mySQL based on user input

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out the best possible way to build this. Here's what I have so far:

Sum up all the widgets sold in a single zip code:

```
select `Widgets`, SUM(`number sold`) as total_sold from mytable where
`Widgets`="Super Widget" and `zip_code`="35801"
```

So far, so good. I can do something similar if I want sales from two zip codes:

```
select `Widgets`, SUM(`number sold`) as total_sold from mytable where 
`Widgets`="Super Widget" and (`zip_code`="35801" or 
`zip_code`="12345")
```

Works great.

What I need to do is be able to set this up such that the user can select multiple zip codes without knowing in advance how many they want. Could be 2 or 20. Is there a way to structure this query as an array or similar? Pseudo-code:

```
select `Widgets`, SUM(`number sold`) as total_sold from mytable where
`Widgets`="Super Widget" and
(`zip_code`=in_array[35801,12345,00124,43562,12441])
```

This would show all the sales in these 5 zip codes. This would be a simple query to build by getting user input on the front end as a comma separated input.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `in`

```
select `Widgets`, SUM(`number sold`) as total_sold from mytable where `Widgets`="Super Widget" and `zip_code` in (35801,12345,00124,43562,12441)
```

Comment: indent your code line with 4 spaces so it will be recognized as code.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Figured there was a function for this, but didn't know what it was.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function (here's an example from the link):

```
SELECT 'wefwf' IN ('wee','wefwf','weg');
```

Applied to your situation, it might look like:

```
...
and (`zip_code` IN ('35801', '12345', '00124', '43562', '12441'))
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can use IN function of SQL, and if you are building this query in PHP code (you added a php tag), then you can use [implode](http://php.net/IMPLODE) function to create the "in array".

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$line = implode(',', $arr);
echo $line; // Will output: a,b,c
```

Notice that writing the values directly to the query string is very dangerous, as it will expose your application to SQL injection attacks.

**UPDATE:**

You can use IN with PDO, with a little workaround - you can create question mark place holder in the query for each one of the values.
We will use [str_repeat](http://php.net/str_repeat) function to create the required question mark place holders, and [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function to remove the last comma.
Assuming your list of values is stored in $arr and your PDO reference is in $pdo:

```
$arr = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3' ...];
$placeHolders = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', cound($arr)), ',');
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($placeHolders)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($arr);
```

The variable $placeHolders will hold a string with '?' place holders for parameters, in the amount of the number of elements in the array, and then you can pass the array to the execute function of the prepeared statement.

Comment: Can I use a PDO function with `IN`?

Comment: This update was a huge help. Thanks. I got it working with a little tweaking.  First, you have "cound" in line 2, and it should be "count". Also, I found that I needed `$arr` to be something like: `$arr = array('35801', '36301');` Just having it in square brackets or curly brackets threw an error for an unexpected '[' or '{'

Comment: Sorry for the typo. The square brakets are avaliable as of php 5.4, before that you must use "array"

Comment: This is a really good answer. Kudos for showing the use of a prepared statement with bind placeholders. +1.